# selecting the correct columns created by mutate_at within a next mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem to select specific variables created by `mutate_at`.

So I have several ratios in groups and I want to calculate for these ratios some kind of borders. This can be easily done with `mutate_at`. But my next step is to use these columns to calculate further values and I am not able to somehow automate this column selection. Is there a convenient way?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(label=letters[1:25],
                 group=rep(1:5, each=5),
                 ratio1=rnorm(25,1,.1),
                 ratio2=rnorm(25,1,.1))

df2 <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ratio1, ratio2),
            funs(rn1=quantile(., probs=c(0.1587), na.rm=TRUE),
                 r0=quantile(., probs=c(0.5), na.rm=TRUE),
                 rp1=quantile(., probs=c(0.8413), na.rm=TRUE)))
```

This creates a data frame where I get for each ratio corresponding columns with quantiles (like `ratio1_rn1`, `ratio1_r0`, etc). I need to use now the related column to calculate significance. I can do this for a single ratio by hand like below, but I would love to do this with `mutate_at` again and somehow select the correct `_rn1`, `_r0` and `_rp1`.

```
df2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  mutate(ratio1_z=ifelse(ratio1 >= 0,
                  (ratio1-ratio1_r0)/(ratio1_rp1-ratio1_r0),
                  (ratio1-ratio1_r0)/(ratio1_rn1-ratio1_r0)),
         ratio1_sigB=.5*pracma::erfc(ratio1_z/sqrt(2)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be more easier with `df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate_at(vars(ratio1, ratio2), funs(list(quantile(., probs = c(0.1587, 0.5, 0.8413), na.rm = TRUE))))`

Comment: You might be right, but the data structure looks moe complicated to me on the first glimpse. Or at least I am not used to handle lists within a `data.frame`. If you have a handy saluting using lists I would be happy to learn this as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your code, I guess you wanted to do the ratios for each corresponding 'ratio' columns with the respective quantiles, and as it is a division, may be the group_by step is not needed

Comment: So I could basically just index each value within the list you mean? Maybe I am not following you and *the* `group_by` *step is not needed*.

Comment: In the final output, are you seeking only the `ratio1_sigB` columns or the other intermediate columns as well?

Comment: If the above code is `df2`, then `map2(df2[3:4], df2[5:6],  ~ .5 * pracma::erfc(ifelse(.x >= 0, (.x - map_dbl(.y, `[`, 2))/(map_dbl(.y, ~ .x[[3]]-.x[[2]])), (.x - map_dbl(.y, `[`, 2)/map_dbl(.y, ~ .x[[1]] - .x[[2]])))/sqrt(2)))`

Comment: The intermediate columns are my poor mans solution at the moment. But I guess it would be nice to make these information somehow retrievable. So `sigB` for `ratio1` and `ratio1` is the most important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create `list` columns and then use `map` to do the subtraction

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>% 
           group_by(group) %>% 
           mutate_at(vars(ratio1, ratio2), 
             funs(new = list(quantile(., probs = c(0.1587, 0.5, 0.8413), 
                 na.rm = TRUE))))

df[paste0(names(df)[3:4], "_sigB")] <- map2(df2[3:4], df2[5:6],  ~
      .5 * pracma::erfc(
          ifelse(.x >= 0, 
            (.x - map_dbl(.y, `[`, 2))/(map_dbl(.y, ~ .x[[3]]-.x[[2]])),
            (.x - map_dbl(.y, `[`, 2)/map_dbl(.y, ~ .x[[1]] - .x[[2]])))/sqrt(2)))

head(df)
#  label group    ratio1    ratio2 ratio1_sigB ratio2_sigB
#1     a     1 0.9373546 0.9943871  0.90859016  0.35742468
#2     b     1 1.0183643 0.9844204  0.50000000  0.50000000
#3     c     1 0.9164371 0.8529248  0.95313974  0.99999928
#4     d     1 1.1595281 0.9521850  0.01013544  0.88133038
#5     e     1 1.0329508 1.0417942  0.40521962  0.01772576
#6     f     2 0.9179532 1.1358680  1.00000000  0.03800840
```

---

Or instead of having multiple `map`s we can `unnest` the temporary object to 'long' format

```
df2 <- df %>% 
           group_by(group) %>%
           mutate_at(vars(ratio1, ratio2), 
             funs(new = list(quantile(., probs = c(0.1587, 0.5, 0.8413), 
                 na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
           unnest 
out <- map2_df(df2[c('ratio1', 'ratio2')], 
               df2[c('ratio1_new', 'ratio2_new')], ~ 
               .5 * pracma::erfc(ifelse(.x > 0,
                (.x - .y[2])/(.y[3]- .y[2]),
                (.x- .y[2])/(.y[1] - .y[2]))/sqrt(2)) %>%
        `[`(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))) %>% # recycling index to subset every 3rd
        rename_all(~ paste0(.x, "_sigB")) %>% 
        bind_cols(df, .) %>%
        as_tibble

head(out, 3)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  label group ratio1 ratio2 ratio1_sigB ratio2_sigB
#  <fct> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 a         1  0.937  0.994       0.909       0.357
#2 b         1  1.02   0.984       0.5         0.5  
#3 c         1  0.916  0.853       0.953       1.000
```

Comment: I guess I need a few minutes to digest this :-) A lot of new concepts but it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Works like a charm!